# How to convert pointers from strtok to strings?

Tags: c, pointers, char, atoi

For example:

```
int main(){
char *str[4];
char data[]="abcd:3:4:5";
str[0]=strtok(data,":");
str[1]=strtok(NULL,":");
str[2]=strtok(NULL,":");
str[3]=strtok(NULL,":");
return 0;
}
```

On the input `"abcd:3:4:5"`, `a` is a string and `b` `c` and `d` are integers. When I use strtok() the broken string is stored in 4 pointers (`str[0]` to `str[3]`), which are immutable. I need to store them in an array where I can change the integers afterwards. I would use `atoi()` but i get the error `'warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast'`. I'd like to store `a`,`b`,`c` e `d` in a non-pointer array, so I can change them afterwards. How do I convert the from `char*` to `char` (afterwards I'll just use `atoi()` on the strings to get the integers).

Comment: If you do not show the instructions that caused the error, we cannot help you to fix them... The function `atoi` can be used directly on the values returned from `strtok`.

Comment: Can you also post the code where you use `atoi()` ? We cant say anything if we dont see it. Also, you don't "store a string into a pointer", the pointer has the address to where the string is stored.

Comment: *When I use strtok() the broken string is stored in 4 pointers (str[0] to str[3]), which are immutable*  What do you mean by "immutable"?  Those pointers point to the memory in your `data` string, and your `data` string is not immutable - if it were, `strtok()` would fail.

Comment: `str[0]` points to changeable chars. `str[0][1] = '%';` is legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To briefly answer your question, the code above should look like this:

```
char input[] = "abcd:18:04:12";

char* p1 = strtok(input, ":");
char* p2 = strtok(NULL, ":");
char* p3 = strtok(NULL, ":");
char* p4 = strtok(NULL, ":");

int val1 = atoi(p2);
int val2 = atoi(p3);
int val3 = atoi(p4);

// and now you can do something with val1, val2 and val3
```

Note that strtok will place a `'\0'` character wherever it sees one of your tokens. If you intend to use the `input` string after, you need a copy of it to pass to strtok.

Comment: Yeah my mistake was trying to store the integers in the char* pointers.It's solved now. Thanks :)